# Workflows with Custom Task Forms in InfoPath - More views in the same form

Tags: workflow, infopath, custom-form, tasks

I'm following [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/StateMachineWorkflows2.aspx) to create custom forms for workflow tasks.

At one point the article says:

> If you are well versed with InfoPath 2010, you can create views in the same form for the various tasks that we have in our workflow. Alternatively, you can create a new form for each task and add it to the solution in a similar manner.

If I were to create more views in the same form, how would I then specify the view to use for a task? I can specify the form with:

```
this.myTask_TaskProperties.TaskType = 1; // 2, 3 ...
```

But how would I specify the view (form + view from the form)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how would I specify the view (form + view from the form)?

Answer: You don't! The following code is sufficient:

```
this.myTask_TaskProperties.TaskType = 1; // 2, 3 ...
```

To select the view you add a "Rule" inside the form (on form load, button click, whatever...) with a "Switch Views" action and select the view based on some condition/button click.